# Snackbar parameter getView() is null in onResponse method of retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

So, I'm trying to code for a login and user registration app. Inside the Snackbar the View is not getting any values and returning nullPoint Exception.

```
response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();   //Line 107
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
            Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The Logcat is giving the following errors.

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.loginregistration.models.ServerResponse.getMessage()' on a null object reference
 at com.learn2crack.loginregistration.RegisterFragment$1.onResponse(RegisterFragment.java:107)
```

Comment: your server response `resp.getMessage()` is returning null, check your API data at postman or other software

Comment: `response.body()` can return `null` if request is not successful, you need to handle it and check using `response.isSuccessful()`

Comment: @chronogenre can you point me somewhere, where I can learn more about this ?

Comment: @farhana sure. I will check it.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh you just need to handle if response is not successful by adding conditional statement. you can check this example though https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/46128c1bc775e87138959b1342b95d059f7456d6/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java#L111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code

```
ServerResponse resp = response.body();
       if(resp != null && resp.getMessage() != null){
        Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();   //Line 107
      }
progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```